# How to add a counter to excel sheet everytime it combines a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, counter

How to add a counter for every new sheet combine? 
Red is the 1st sheet combine
Yellow is the 2nd sheet combine 
Green is the 3rd sheet combine

No need to add color .... however i been trying to add a counter in but i do not know how to do it ... and place it above each data imported

it might be my way of using the macro wrongly ...

hope someone helps me out ....

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U32Bo.png)

```
Sub GetSheets()'Update Excel Junction.com
Path = "C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"

'Set references up-front
Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")
lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!
lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!

'Set the initial destination range
Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 2)



'Loop through all sheets
For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
    If wksSrc.Name <> "Combine" Then

        'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
        lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

        'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
        With wksSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, lngLastCol))
            rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
        End With

        'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
        lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 2, 1)
    End If
Next wksSrc
End Sub


'''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
With Sheet
lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet
        lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedColNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: Add a counter where? You have a Sub `CombineDataFromAllSheets`, I guess you could count every time it is run. What have you tried so far in counting?

Comment: I would like to have a counter added at the color comments... everytime when a new sheet is combine ... the counter will +1 ..... that's is what i would like it to do ...

Except i do not know how to go around writing a script for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to add a static counter, but this will be reset each time you open the workbook. The more resilient approach will be to find the last counter and add one.

I am not able to create fully tested code here, but the following should give enough of an idea. Remember that proper indenting and `Option Explicit` are your friends. Also, I have not put any other optimisations in your code - e.g. check how many times you really need to set your destination range and where it is best to set it.

```
Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()
Dim importCounter as Long '**** Added this 
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long
    'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"
    'Set references up-front
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")
    lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!
    lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!

    'Set the initial destination range
    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 2)

    '**** Find and set the Counter - not tested for error conditions (what if the sheet is empty?)
    importCounter = wksDst.Cells(Range("A" & lngDstLastRow).End(xlUp).Row,1)

    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Combine" Then

            'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

            'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
            With wksSrc
                '**** increment and insert the counter
                '**** in order to do this, had to fix rngDst, set it where it is used rather then too early.
                Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
                importCounter = importCounter + 1
                rngDst = importCounter
                lngDstLastRow = lngDstLastRow  + 1
                Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 2)

                Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, lngLastCol))
                rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
            End With

            'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 2, 1)
        End If
    Next wksSrc
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @AJD, thanks for helping me out with the counter alot. I appreciate your time and thank you for contributing to my post :cry: